# Do I need pthread_exit if I don't care of return value

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

If I don't care about the return status of my thread, would I need to have a pthread_exit?

I'm wondering if there might be some subtle resource problems associated with not calling pthread_exit in my datached pthreads.

Thanks.

Comment: read manual http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_exit.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to call `pthread_exit()`. Returning from the thread function would work equally well, and will not leak any resources (of course, you still have to ensure that *your* code doesn't have any leaks).

Answer (score 7):

The purpose `pthread_exit()` is to return the exit code if any other threads that *joins*.

From the [manual](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html):

```
   Performing a return from the start function of any thread other than the main
   thread results in an implicit call to pthread_exit(), using the function's
   return value as the thread's exit status.
```

So, it makes no difference if you don't use it.