# Mac OS X pthreads fake return address

Tags: macos, pthreads, mach

In the OS X pthreads implementation (http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.26/pthreads/thread_setup.c?txt) they provide a fake return address on the thread stack (line 140):

```
    ts->rip = (uintptr_t) routine;

    /*
    ** We need to simulate a 16-byte aligned stack frame as if we had
    ** executed a call instruction. The stack should already be aligned
    ** before it comes to us and we don't need to push any arguments,
    ** so we shouldn't need to change it.
    */

    ts->rdi = (uintptr_t) thread;   /* argument to function */
    *--sp = 0;            /* fake return address */
    ts->rsp = (uintptr_t) sp;   /* set stack pointer */
```

I do not understand how this will not crash with an illegal instruction/segfault when the function that the thread is executing calls 'ret' and pops that return address from the stack. Can anyone explain how this is prevented/handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking at the rest of the code, I can only venture a guess.  My intuition says, the called thread procedure (the user-supplied `start_routine` parameter) should **never** return to the calling function.

Think about it: if the new thread *did* return, you would have two threads running over the same original code path.  I imagine that the thread function that is *actually* called is a wrapper that calls the user-supplied `start_routine`. When the `start_routine` returns, the wrapper then calls `pthread_exit`.

```
(main thread)
     v
pthread_create
     v
thread_setup  (sets up stack), and spawns new thread
     v                                     |
return to main thread                      |
                                           |
                                           |
                                           v
                                      wrapper_function
                                           v
                    user-supplied    start_routine
                                           |   (returns)
                                           v
                                wrapper_function  calls
                                           v
                                     pthread_exit
```

Again, this is just a guess, but the whole point is, the new thread should *never* return to the code that called `pthread_create`. The purpose of the wrapper then would be to *ensure* that `pthread_exit` gets called.

I would have to see what they are passing as `routine` to `thread_setup`.

My feelings are confirmed by the fact that [you don't have to call `pthread_exit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990067/do-i-need-pthread-exit-if-i-dont-care-of-return-value).

Comment: Indeed, the "routine" passed to `_pthread_setup` seems always to be `_pthread_body` (search for that identifier in this file: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.26/pthreads/pthread.c ) which does exactly what you speculate the wrapper would do.  The *actual* thread worker (the function pointer originally passed to `pthread_create`) is stashed inside the `pthread_t` object.  I don't know why `thread_setup` is in its own file, but this kind of low-level code is often a big mess.

Comment: And come to think of it, the point of the "fake return address" in `thread_setup` is probably to ensure that if the wrapper ever does return (which would be a bug in the C library, but still) you get a *predictable* crash instead of jumping to some random address that might actually have code at it.

Comment: @Zack Thanks for confirming all of that! I didn't really have the time to look into it when I answered, so I appreciate you following up.

Comment: This all makes sense. The actual user function is called as an argument to _pthread_exit, which then kills its own thread with thread_terminate, never returning to the user.